# Ubuntu machine connects to an unknown wireless network

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, network-manager

Ubuntu 12.04 machine connects to an unknown wireless network automatically even if the connection is not visible in the list of wireless connections. This seems to be like a rogue network, how should I prevent auto connection to this wireless network.

I have 2 wireless networks, but only one of them is configured to auto connect to a certain network.

Comment: If that network doesn't show up, how do you know that you are connected to it?

Comment: If I just randomly check my wireless connection (on the top right hand menu), it seems to be connected (to the rogue wireless network) sometimes not sure how | why that happens. I have seen the wireless connection (say c1) switch from what I had connected earlier, to this rogue wireless network (say MarvelApx).

Comment: Appreciate pointers on this issue.

Comment: I still don't have a concrete way to avoid this, any pointers.

Comment: I only can suggest that you (as soon as you detect that connection) try what Raja suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Open Network Manager and choose Wireless and select Particular connections and select edit  and **uncheck** Connect Automatically button and save.

Use this image for reference

[image]

Edit:

We have one more solution , Block that SSID

```
#!/bin/sh

SSID=`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -I\
 | grep ' SSID:' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | tr -d ' '`

if [[ $SSID = "RLSPOT001" || "RLAVID001" || "RLSHEE001" || "RLGUES001" || "RLBGAS001" || "BTFON" ]]; then
/usr/sbin/networksetup -setairportpower en1 off
fi
```

Where RLSPOT001,RLAVID001 are SSID's that you want to block. Is there any way you can figure what SSID you are connecting ?

then above script can  help  if you run at startup.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, this wireless connection is not visible in the list of my network connections at all.

Comment: You said its connecting right . it must get connected to some connection right. Try to delete that connection.

Comment: I have 2 connections (c1, c2) and c1 is connect by default. My machine gets connected to this unknown network (MarvelApx) which is not listed in my settings at all. Hope its clear, maybe someone else in the vicinity is starting up a modem/router which is causing this to happen.

Comment: This is a Ubuntu machine, I don't think the above script will work. How do I find the SSID?

Comment: If you just google , million ways bro . Any way go with http://www.thelinuxgeek.com/content/find-hidden-ssids

Answer (score 0):

In the wireless menu in the notification area of the panel, there should be an option near the bottom called "Edit Connections...". Select the unidentified network from the list in the window that appears and press the "Delete" button on the right side of the window.

Comment: It doesn't appear in the list of Available Wireless Connection, but it appears from nowhere and without my realization it gets connected to that network.